# Refactoring the a subquery within a select statement to a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got a table of products and a table of widgets.

A product is built from a number of widgets and I've got a linking table which shows which widgets are linked to which products.

Widgets can be marked as `expired`, which means they are not eligible to be added to any new products.

Schema and sample data in the following **[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2ea7/3)** -

I want a query that shows all the eligible widgets for a particular product given the following rules:

1. A widget should not be shown if it is marked as expired.
2. As an exception to the above rule - If a widget is marked as expired, but is already linked to a product, then it should be shown.
3. If a widget has already been linked to the product, it should be marked as `'selected'`

I've got the following query which works, and satisfies all the above rules:

```
select 
    data.WidgetName, 
    data.expired,
    case 
        when data.ID in (select data_id from Widget_link where productId = 1)   
        then 1 
        else 0 
    end as selected
from Widget_data data
left outer join Widget_link link
    on data.ID = link.data_id and data.expired = 1
where (data.expired = 0 or (data.expired = 1 and link.productId = 1))
```

I'd like to find a way to refactor the sub-query within the select part of the query to some kind of join. I'm trying to create a view which I can filter using just a `where` clause, rather than having the `productId` in two places. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On simplification your query can solely be evaluated based on JOIN like below, and there is no need for inner query at all.

```
select data.WidgetName,
     case when link.id is not null then 1 else 0 end as selected
from Widget_data data
left outer join Widget_link link
    on data.ID = link.data_id and link.productId = 1
where data.expired=0 or link.id is not null
```

**[Demo SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2ea7/5)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL CTE (Common Table Expression)](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18) to cover the results from a SELECT list, and use in a single SQL statement

You can even create [SQL statements with multiple CTE's](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-multiple-cte-syntax-sql-cte-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) in your code

What I suggest is can be summarized visually as follows

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ..... FROM .....
),
other_cte AS (
  SELECT ..... FROM .....
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
INNER JOIN other_cte ON...
```